# Have to refresh page in order for simple JS code to work

Tags: jquery

I have an issue when running simple javascript code to keep my banner static on top of the page while you scroll through the content. The code I am using works, but unfortunately sometimes you have to refresh the page for it to work. I have disabled pop up blockers as well.

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 
 var navOffset = jQuery("header").offset().top;

 jQuery("header").wrap('<div class="header-placeholder"></div>');
 jQuery(".header-placeholder").height(jQuery("header").outerHeight());


 jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

  if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
   jQuery("header").addClass("fixed");
  } else {
   jQuery("header").removeClass("fixed");
  }

 });

});
```

The banner on top of the web page is in a header tag.

I'm not really sure why this happens as the code seems fine. Admittedly I do not have much JS experience, but I followed a video tutorial to accomplish this and it seems like the author of the video tutorial had no issues. If it helps at all here is the link to the video I followed.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utonytGKodc

Thanks for the help everyone. I have tried searching for similar problem with other people and found answers to more complex code that doesn't seem like it could be applied to what I have.

Comment: do you have a working example such as a codepen, jsfiddle or better yet can you add a working snippet here?

Comment: Hello everyone. It seems like the problem has been solved. For some reason, it appears that this will only happen offline when I open the html files into my browser from my local computer. When I updated the files on the web host this doesn't seem to occur anymore. It would still be interesting to know as to why this is.

Answer (score 2):

You're only calculating `navOffset` when you open the page, and not on scroll. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("header").wrap('<div class="header-placeholder"></div>');
    jQuery(".header-placeholder").height(jQuery("header").outerHeight());

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var navOffset = jQuery("header").offset().top;

        if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
            jQuery("header").addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            jQuery("header").removeClass("fixed");
        }
    });
});
```

P.S. If you don't want to keep retyping `jQuery`, you can just use the dollary sign `$`, such as: `$('header')`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will make the changes on my code immediately.

Comment: It seems like your code has worked once I uploaded the page online. Thank you very much for you help, very much appreciated.